# Going Back and Forth in commit log

Tags: git

I have initialized a git repository and added a number of commits to it.Now I want to do the following.

1.How to go back in point of time that is if  There are commits A,B,C,,,Y and currently I am in commit Y how can I change my project when it was before commit E?
2.By the same token if I have gone back in point of time will I be able to go from commit E to commit X which lies in future?

I know above may sound a bit stupid  I apologize for my stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `git checkout` does. You can just `git checkout E`, where `E` is the SHA identifying the commit you want to time-travel to, and your working tree will change to reflect what it was at that time. You can then use the same mechanism to go back to `Y`: `git checkout Y`.